# How to check if a repo exists?

Tags: git, bash

or is there a command line option to use with

```
git remote rm godaddy
```

so that it does not throw an error if the repository does not exist?

What would this command line option be?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the `git ls-remote` to test if repo exist.

Try running this in a folder without a repository in it:

```
git ls-remote https://github.com/git/git
```

Answer (score 1):

Commands do not "throw error". They print messages to `stderr` and use non-zero exit code.

To mute an error message you can redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null`.

```
git remote rm nonexistent 2>/dev/null
```

To ignore non-zero exit code, you can use `|| :` like this:

```
git remote rm nonexistent 2>/dev/null || :
```

The exit code of this last command will always be 0.
If the remote existed, it will be deleted, if it didn't exist, the error message will be discarded.

There's a caveat though. If the remote exists but deletion fails for some reason, the error message and the exit code will be hidden. This could be improved, by hiding the error message only when exit code is 128, which happens when the repository didn't exist. But I doubt it's worth it:

```
out=$(git remote rm $repo 2>&1)
[ $? = 128 ] || echo "$out"
```